# How do I compare my release_date and if they match then put them in that order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

[This is the order I want my movies to  be in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkxeP.png)

This is the code of how I sorted the favorites release_date :

```
 sort_movieDates = () => {
    let releases = this.state.favorites.map(favorites=>favorites.release_date)
    let newFavorites=this.state.favorites.release_date;
    releases.sort();
    console.log(releases)

}
```

What I want to do is that to compare the favorites release_date with [the movie details in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWgV3.png) . If the favorites release_date match then I want it to be added in that order. For example since Jurassic World: the Fallen Kingdom has the release_date of 2018-06-06, it will be #6 because that's where that release_date is in releases. So how do I do this?

Comment: You need to pass a function to `Array.prototype.sort()` in order to sort objects in a meaningful way

Comment: It's very hard for us to create a working example of a solution when the data you give us is a picture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a javascript array of objects by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430561/how-to-sort-a-javascript-array-of-objects-by-date)

Comment: Please look again, I changed the question a little

Answer (score 0):

all of this will help i think

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

https://davidwalsh.name/array-sort

https://en.proft.me/2015/11/14/sorting-array-objects-number-string-date-javascrip/